# Unable to boot the OS - namespace lookup failure

Tags: dual-boot, shell, acpi

**Hardware:** Lenovo Y700 (i7-6700HQ, 8GB, 960M)

**Setup:** Dual Boot with Windows 10 on an HDD.

Worked fine for a couple of weeks. Now it falls down to a shell every time I try to boot the Linux. Windows works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955467/dev-sda1-contains-a-file-system-with-errors-check-forced/955504) on the askubuntu with command `fsck -f /dev/sda1`